# MySql Join and subquery

Tags: mysql

Ok, as easiest as i can explain.

- There are many `child.sid` to `parent.id`.
- There are many `child.nid` to `child.sid`
- There are many `child.id` to `child.nid`

`child.id` is just the id of a child row. And each row has `rating` column.

In the query i'm grouping by `child.nid`.  But the results that are being returned are the first entry(lowest `child.id`) for each `nid`.  What i want is the highest rated `child.id` for that `nid`.

```
$construct =  "SELECT child.* FROM outcomes child 
    JOIN outcomes parent on parent.id=child.sid JOIN    
    WHERE (parent.name LIKE '%$search%') GROUP BY child.nid,child.sid
    ORDER BY child.rating DESC";
```

I've tried `ORDER BY child.rating DESC` but this needs to happen before the `GROUP BY child.nid`.

Any idea how to solve this problem? subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely wrap it in another query like this:

```
$construct =  "SELECT * FROM (SELECT child.* FROM child 
JOIN parent on parent.id=child.sid JOIN    
WHERE (parent.name LIKE '%$search%') GROUP BY child.nid,child.sid)
ORDER BY child.rating DESC";
```

Watch the EXPLAIN report, though and check the performance optimization when doing anything like this.

EDIT: Updated the code to remove reference to parent database.

Comment: tried that and it i an error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server ..." . it still doesn't work

Comment: I just pasted your code and put a query around so I assumed your original query was correct but it looks wrong. I updated it to remove the two instances of the word outcomes which looks to be the problem.